# How to prevent gcc from generating PT_GNU_STACK program header?

Tags: linux, gcc, stack

My gcc 4.8 always generates a `PT_GNU_STACK` program header in the ELF executable on Linux.

When I use `gcc -S`, in the `.s` file (assembly file), gcc generates a line `.section        .note.GNU-stack,"",@progbits`. Without this line the `PT_GNU_STACK` program header disappears from the ELF executable.

Is it possible to specify a command-line flag for gcc so that it won't generate the `PT_GNU_STACK` program header?

(I don't care if the stack is executable or not, either solution is fine for me.)

It looks like it's not possible to prevent gcc 4.8 from emitting `.section        .note.GNU-stack,"",@progbits`, because this is hardcoded in `file_end_indicate_exec_stack` defined in `gcc/varasm.c`. But maybe there is another solution such a command-line flag to `ld`.

Comment: I don't know if you can stop it, but you can force it to a 0-size. Because the link-loader uses a 0-size as a signal for NX stacks, you probably cannot do it. Gentoo and other PaX kernels may be different, however. To enable the NX-stack/-0-sized stack use `-Wl,-z,noexecstack`. If there is ASM in the project, then you need to tell the assembler too with `-Wa,--noexecstack`. You should also specify `-Wtrampolines` during compile. Trampolines write executable code on the stack, and they cause a silent loss of NX stacks without the GCC warning.

Comment: @jww: Thank you for your reply. Please note that `gcc -Wl,-z,noexecstack -Wa,--noexecstack` didn't work, `PT_GNU_STACK` is still there.

Comment: @jww: Please note that `gcc -Wl,-z,execstack -Wa,--execstack` didn't work either, PT_GNU_STACK is still there.